# Postfix re-route incoming email address

Tags: linux, email, debian, postfix

How do i re-route an **incoming email address** to a our domain using postfix.The mail should not go to spam mail. The sender should get a failure sending message. Can anyone please help me to it.

Comment: So, you want to bounce the message but still take a copy of it?  WHY?

Comment: Somethings's not right here...womble's right(+1), the only reason I can think to use this arrangement is to track responses to email addresses.  Can you elaborate a bit as to why you want your email server to be fundimentally broken?

Comment: Trying out an experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html says:

```
   Postfix  version  2.3  and  later  support  RFC 3463-style
   enhanced status codes.  If a  command  terminates  with  a
   non-zero  exit  status, and the command output begins with
   an enhanced status code, this status code takes precedence
   over the non-zero exit status.
```

So if you pipe the addreses you want to return fmilures for over to a
command and then 1) output an enhanced status code from RFC3463 and then
2) return a non-zero exit code, the sender will get the enhanced status code
that you sent.